# 文字列の数字でソートした後、連続した数字になるように文字列を書き直すには。

Tags: python, python3, sort

pythonのosライブラリのos.listdir()で格納した以下のようなファイルリストを、sortした後に連続した数字になるようにファイル名を変更したいです。

```
sample1.png 
sample15.png    
sample21.png    
sample27.png    
sample31.png    
sample35.gif    
sample41.jpg    
sample8.png
sample13.png    
sample18.png
```

この例では全て数字の前をsampleとしているため単純なsort()でも順番を整えることができますが、実際にはいろんなファイル名が考えられるため、数字の方でソートしなければなりません。（ファイル名には必ず数字がつきます）つまり、上のリストを：

```
sample1.png
sample8.png 
sample13.png
sample15.png  
sample18.png  
sample21.png    
sample27.png    
sample31.png    
sample35.gif
```

のように数字順にした後、連続した番号にするため最終的に以下のようなファイル名に変更したいです。

```
sample1.png
sample2.png 
sample3.png
sample4.png  
sample5.png  
sample6.png    
sample7.png    
sample8.png    
sample9.gif
```

幸い、ファイル名の変更はos.rename()で可能ですが、その前にsortしないといけません。
以下の二つを試していますが、どちらもIndexError: list index out of rangeになってしまいます。
どなたか良い方法をご存知ないですか？

```
files = os.listdir(path)
def sort_by_num(test_string):
        return list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', test_string)))[0]
files.sort(key=sort_by_num)
```

```
files.sort(key=lambda file : list(
        map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', file)))[0])
```

Comment: ちなみに単純に数字部分を割り振り直すだけだと、ファイルをリネームしていく途中で名前が重複したりする可能性はありませんか？ いったん先頭に`ZZZZ`等の特定の文字列を付けてリネームしてから、最後にそれを外した形にリネームする2つのステップを踏んだりする必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: @metropolis さんの回答と、後から行われた別質問のソースコード＆呼び出し方を合わせて見ると、Pythonスクリプトと処理対象ファイル群を同じディレクトリに入れてしまって、そのディレクトリをカレントディレクトリとしてパスパラメータを指定せずに実行したのでは？ そしてPythonスクリプト自身のファイル名には数字が付いていないので該当のエラーになったとか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイル名（正確には拡張子を除く basename）の数字以外の部分は何であれ，後ろの数字の部分だけを取り出してソートして再度1から順番に採番して，元の名前に新たに採番した番号を付けた名前にリネームするということでよいのでしょうか．

基本的に「ファイル名から数字部分を取り出す」「ソートする」「リネームする」を同時にやろうとせずに，順番にやった方がいいのではないかと思います．その方針で実装したコード例を以下に示します．

```
import os
import re


def parse_filename(fn):
    """Parse a filename into (original, base, num, ext)"""
    m = re.match(r'(\D*)(\d*)\.(.*)$', fn)
    return (m[0], m[1], int(m[2]), m[3])


def main():
    path = 'path/to/somewhere'
    filenames = os.listdir(path)

    parsed_filenames = [parse_filename(fn) for fn in filenames]

    for i, m in enumerate(sorted(parsed_filenames, key=lambda x: x[2])):
        os.rename(path + '/' + m[0],
                  path + '/' + m[1] + str(i + 1) + '.' + m[3])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

このコードでやっていることを念のため簡単に説明しておくと，まず `os.listdir(path)` で取得した各ファイル名を `parse_filename()` 関数で以下の要素を持つタプルに分解します．

- オリジナルのファイル名 (str)
- basename の非数字部分 (str)
- basename の数字部分 (int)
- 拡張子 (str)

その上で，basename の数字部分を用いて普通にソートし，最後に for 文の中で目的のリネームを実行しています．

Comment: 初心者質問で申し訳ないのですが、私がやろうとするとNameError: name 'parse_filename' is not definedでエラーになってしまいます。

Comment: `def parse_filename(fn):` 以下の3行もコピーしましたか？ 例示したのはプログラム全体なので，動作確認には一旦すべてをコピーした単一のファイルにして実行するとよいかもしれません．

Answer (score 0):

> ファイル名には必ず数字がつきます
>
> 以下の二つを試していますが、どちらもIndexError: list index out of rangeになってしまいます。

`IndexError: list index out of range` が発生するということは、ファイル名に数字を含まないものが存在する、という事になります(`re.findall(r'\d+', file)` が empty list を返している)。

```py
import re

files = [
  'foo3.png',
  'bar2.jpg',
  'baz1.gif',
  'bitmap.bmp',
]

files.sort(key=lambda file : list(
        map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', file)))[0])
```

**実行結果**

```sh
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    files.sort(key=lambda file : list(
  File "test.py", line 10, in <lambda>
    files.sort(key=lambda file : list(
IndexError: list index out of range
```

なので、ファイル名に数字を含まないものはリストの最後に配置する様にします。
※ `Walrus operator`(セイウチ演算子)を使用していますので Python 3.8 よりも以前のバージョンでは動作しません

```
import re
import math

files = [
  'dismays1.png',
  'pellet15.png',
  'emulsifies21.png',
  'classicist27.png',
  'dysfunctions31.png',
  'quadrangle35.gif',
  'bitmap.bmp',
  'cargos41.jpg',
  'wheels8.png',
  'heartlessly13.png',
  'attains18.png',
]

files.sort(key=lambda x: int(n[0]) if (n:=re.findall(r'\d+', x)) else math.inf)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(files)

#
['dismays1.png',
 'wheels8.png',
 'heartlessly13.png',
 'pellet15.png',
 'attains18.png',
 'emulsifies21.png',
 'classicist27.png',
 'dysfunctions31.png',
 'quadrangle35.gif',
 'cargos41.jpg',
 'bitmap.bmp']
```